# Solidity CRUD trying to call All data return instead of one by one using ID

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I have created a solidity that record data CRUD like where I can create read update delete but I want to create a readAll function wondering how can I write in solidity since I write like below it does not work. For calling with id it return the correct but not readAll. Looking forward for your help <3

example

```
function readAllTask() public view returns (uint, uint256, uint256) {
        return (tasks.id, tasks.stackAddress, tasks.nftId);  <============= return everything
    }
```

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

contract RecordData {
    
    struct Task {
        uint id;
        uint256 stackAddress;
        uint256 nftId;
    }
    
    Task[] tasks;
    uint nextId; // default value 0, add public to see the value
    
    function createTask(uint256 _stackAddress, uint256  _nftId) public {
        tasks.push(Task(nextId, _stackAddress, _nftId));
        nextId++;
    }

    
    function findIndex(uint _id) internal view returns (uint) {
        for (uint i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
            if (tasks[i].id == _id) {                
                return i;
            }
        }
        revert("Task not found");
    }
    
    function updateTask(uint _id, uint256 _stackAddress, uint256 _nftId) public {
        uint index =  findIndex(_id);
        tasks[index].stackAddress = _stackAddress;
        tasks[index].nftId = _nftId;
    }
    
    function readTask(uint _id) public view returns (uint, uint256, uint256) {
        uint index = findIndex(_id);
        return (tasks[index].id, tasks[index].stackAddress, tasks[index].nftId);
    }
    
    function deleteTask(uint _id) public {
        uint index = findIndex(_id);
        delete tasks[index];
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an array of structs:

```
function readAllTask() public view returns (Task[] memory) {
    return tasks;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have reason to do it, but just a remind that saving the data into blockchain is not a good deal, due to the high cost.

---

If you would like to return all the task, then simply make the `tasks` public. Solidity automatically assign a get function for it.

If you would like to get some specific content of task struct, then consider something like this:

```
function readAllTask() public view returns (uint, uint256, uint256 [] memory) {
        // something
    }
```